# Does GO statement has priority over edge types when traversing edges?

Tags: nebula-graph

I'm writing a query statement like this:

```
GO 1 steps from "10.2.29.88" OVER edge_ref,edge_attack YIELD distinct properties(edge) as v limit [10000]
```

Will the 10,000 edges be consistently taken from `edge_ref` first, or is it completely random?

Answer (score 0):

the priority is basically random as NebulaGraph data is partitioned.